# How to get information from SVN repository?

Tags: svn

We are using SVN for version control for our web application.

I want to know details like total number of check-in, check-ins by particular user.  Is there any tool which can help me to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nifty tool which generates some static html report:

http://www.statsvn.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can get Statistics from the [Show Log dialog in TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html#tsvn-dug-showlog-5). Remember to click the "Show All" button first, otherwise you'll only get stats on a limited range of revisions.

Answer (score 1):

You could just write one (say, in Perl or Python) based on the `svn log` and `svn annotate` commands...

Comment: If you go this route, the `--xml` switch on the `svn log` command is rather useful.

Answer (score 0):

Does not `revision` give you total number of check-ins? For check-ins by user you could write a simple script. Run `svn log` command, and then parse the input using regex, or any programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/). StatSVN retrieves information from a Subversion repository and generates various tables and charts describing the project development, e.g. timeline for the lines of code, contribution of each developer etc.